# Inner rounded corners on div/img

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I need to style a dummy or normal picture like this, and I have it surrounded with a div with shadows. 
I don’t know how to make the lower right inner corner. And I need to change the gender symbol inside that corner. It’s easy to change the symbol with angular, but I need a span or div to do it in.
Any suggestions to a proper CSS for this?

[image]

Comment: Give us some code to work please ;-)

Comment: Just for clarity (as my comment got auto removed with the closure), you should look at the SVG or clip-path options because you are looking for the inward curve on an `img` or a `div` (which I assume has an image background). The other approaches won't work for you.

Comment: I dont have any code yet..

Comment: Harry: Do you have a link or some code to get started with?